# Deserialize json character as TsEnum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, json-deserialization

I have a TsEnum class where I store all my enum value. And I just added an extra value to the list but it will not deserialize a string. All other enum value deserialize fine just not the newest one I just added.

Code

```
var x  = (SentencePartModelBase)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value.ToString(), type);
```

String Deserialize

```
{{
  "Type": 204,
  "Units": {
    "Id": "41",
    "Name": "mg",
    "GroupName": "1"
  },
  "SequenceOrder": 2,
  "IsInvalid": true
}}
```

[TsEnum]

```
public enum MaxDoseUnits
{
    [EnumDisplayName("international units")]
    [EnumGroupName("2")]
    [EnumDictionaryId("f4ac115b-5bb1-4653-83af-3a4bef9a80e1")]
    [EnumOrder("")]
    Iu = 41,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [EnumMember(Value = "Id")] attribue to the enum

```
var x  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

classes

```
public enum MaxDoseUnits
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Iu")]

    [EnumDisplayName("international units")]
    [EnumGroupName("2")]
    [EnumDictionaryId("f4ac115b-5bb1-4653-83af-3a4bef9a80e1")]
    [EnumOrder("")]
    Iu = 41
}
public class Units
{
    public MaxDoseUnits Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public Units Units { get; set; }
    public int SequenceOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsInvalid { get; set; }
}
```

to test, you can deserialize this json without any problem too

```
{
  "Type": 204,
  "Units": {
    "Id": "Iu",   //or "Id":41, works too
    "Name": "mg",
    "GroupName": "1"
  },
  "SequenceOrder": 2,
  "IsInvalid": true
}
```

Comment: why do I need the EnumMember if I have the  `Iu = 41`? should it just use that?

Comment: @Jefferson It is a good question. Yes ,  you don't  need to use it if you have Id for example.  But if you have a string  of enum in a json , you will need enum to deserialize it properly. This is why I posted this example for you.  And you have to understand that Id is not user friendly. You can  not show Id on the screen, but only  text. This are enumeration for or you have to create a look up table instead.

Comment: would I be able to see the enum object ? is it in the type object? I like to make sure its loading an updated file and not anything from Cache?

Comment: @Jefferson You can see in my class public MaxDoseUnits Id { get; set; },  not public int Id { get; set; } this is what makes a difference and will work with string and with integer

Comment: Yes I have a  `public DictionaryItem<MaxDoseUnits> Units { get; set; }` that is the enum enum MaxDoseUnits